# Adding multiple input field with a dynamic table laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I want to store data from a dynamic table, with multiple field. Its working if i want to store one table fields but the problem is with (Add more button) storing more than one table fields.

this is my **controller**

```
if($request->type==='quiz'){
  //dd($request->all());     

     $quiz_id = DB::table('quizes')->insertGetId([
      'content_id' =>$content_id,
      'c_title'=>$request->c_title,
      'question'=>$request->question,
      'created_at'=>now(), 

  ]);

    //return $request->all();

    foreach ($request->c_title as $key => $value) {

      $new_answer->content_id=$content_id;
      $new_answer->quiz_id=$quiz_id;
      $new_answer->c_title =$request->c_title[$key];
      $new_answer->question=$request->question[$key];

      foreach ($request->answer as $key => $value) {
        $new_answer = new answer();
        $new_answer->answer =$request->answer[$key];
        $new_answer->correct=$request->correct[$key] ? 1 :0;
      }


  if(!$new_answer->save()){

  // handle error here
  }
   }
  return redirect()->route('content.index')->with('success', 'Content Successfully Recorded');
 }
```

}

And this is my **addcontent.blade.php** blade

```
       else if(type==='quiz'){

        append_type=  '<div class="form-group">'+
                      '<label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">Content Title:</label>'+
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+
                   '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Content Title" name="c_title">'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                   '<label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4'+
                    'col-xs-12">Question:</label>'+
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+
                      '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Question"'+
                       'name="question">'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h3 align="center"> PLEASE ADD THE ANSWER  HERE</h3>'+ 
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                     '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
                      '<input type="hidden" name="correct[]" value="1"  class="correct_1"/>'+
                      '<div class="checkbox" >'+
                  '<label><input type="checkbox" name="optradio"  value="1" id="option_1" checked>'+
                  'Correct?</label>'+
                     '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+           
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+

                   '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" Type the Answer"'+
                   'name="answer[]">'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '</div> '+
                     '<div class="form-group">'+
                     '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
                     '<input type="hidden" name="correct[]" value="0" class="correct_2"/>'+
                   '<div class="checkbox">'+
             '<label><input type="checkbox" name="optradio" value="2" id="option_2">Correct?</label>'+
                     '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+          
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+   
                        '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="'+
                         'Type the Answer" name="answer[]">'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+ 
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                     '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
                      '<input type="hidden" name="correct[]" value="0" class="correct_3"/>'+
                        '<div class="checkbox">'+
                   '<label><input type="checkbox" name="optradio" value="3" id="option_3">'+
                   'Correct?</label>'+
                     '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+
                        '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="'+ 
                        'Type the Answer" name="answer[]">'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+ 
                    '<div class="form-group">'+ 
                      '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
                      '<input type="hidden" name="correct[]" value="0" class="correct_4"/>'+
                      '<div class="checkbox">'+ 
                   '<label><input type="checkbox" name="optradio" value="4" id="option_4">'+
                   'Correct?</label>'+
                     '</div>'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+
                        '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="'+
                         'Type the Answer" name="answer[]">'+
                            '<button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success"'+
                       'style="margin-top:5px;">'+
                      'Add More</button></td>'+   
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'; 
                     $('#default_type_form').html(append_type);

            var html='<div class="append_quiz"><div class="form-group">'+
                      '<label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">Content Title:</label>'+
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+
                   '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Content Title" name="c_title">'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                   '<label class="control-label col-md-4 col-sm-4'+
                    'col-xs-12">Question:</label>'+
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+
                      '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Question"'+
                       'name="question">'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<h3 align="center"> PLEASE ADD THE ANSWER  HERE</h3>'+ 
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                     '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
                      '<input type="hidden" name="correct[]" value="1"  class="correct_1"/>'+
                      '<div class="checkbox" >'+
                  '<label><input type="checkbox" name="optradio"  value="1" id="option_1" checked>'+
                  'Correct?</label>'+
                     '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+           
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+

                   '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder=" Type the Answer"'+
                   'name="answer[]">'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '</div> '+
                     '<div class="form-group">'+
                     '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
                     '<input type="hidden" name="correct[]" value="0" class="correct_2"/>'+
                   '<div class="checkbox">'+
             '<label><input type="checkbox" name="optradio" value="2" id="option_2">Correct?</label>'+
                     '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+          
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+   
                        '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="'+
                         'Type the Answer" name="answer[]">'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+ 
                    '<div class="form-group">'+
                     '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
                      '<input type="hidden" name="correct[]" value="0" class="correct_3"/>'+
                        '<div class="checkbox">'+
                   '<label><input type="checkbox" name="optradio" value="3" id="option_3">'+
                   'Correct?</label>'+
                     '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+
                        '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="'+ 
                        'Type the Answer" name="answer[]">'+
                      '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+ 
                    '<div class="form-group">'+ 
                      '<div class="col-sm-2">'+
                      '<input type="hidden" name="correct[]" value="0" class="correct_4"/>'+
                      '<div class="checkbox">'+ 
                   '<label><input type="checkbox" name="optradio" value="4" id="option_4">'+
                   'Correct?</label>'+
                     '</div>'+
                      '</div>'+
                      '<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">'+
                        '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="'+
                         'Type the Answer" name="answer[]">'+
                   '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove_quiz" style="margin-top:5px;">'+
                      'X</button></td></div>';

      $('#add').click(function(e){
      $('#default_type_form').append(html);
      quiz_i++;
         //remove rows from the form
      $(".remove_quiz").on('click',function(){
      $(this).closest('div .append_quiz').fadeOut(function(){
      $(this).remove();
      });
         quiz_i--;
      });

      });
               var $radios = $('input[name="optradio"]');
                $radios.change(function(){

                  if($(this).val()==1){

                      $('#correct_1').val();
                       $('#correct_2').val(0);
                        $('#correct_3').val(0);
                         $('#correct_4').val(0);
                  }
                  else if($(this).val()==2){
                    $('#correct_2').val(1);
                     $('#correct_1').val(0);
                        $('#correct_3').val(0);
                         $('#correct_4').val(0);
                  } 
                    else if($(this).val()==3){
                    $('#correct_3').val(1);
                     $('#correct_1').val(0);
                      $('#correct_2').val(0);
                       $('#correct_4').val(0);
                  }
                 else if($(this).val()==4){
                    $('#correct_4').val(1);
                     $('#correct_2').val(0);
                      $('#correct_3').val(0);
                      $('#correct_1').val(0);
                  }


           console.dir($radios);

     });


      }

    });


  });
</script>
```

if some one can help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: please try to specify the problem with less script. here you showing long script.

Comment: @EmtiazZahid the system showing me this error ( Invalid argument supplied for foreach() )

Comment: what its showing if you try to dd($request->all()) in your controller method

Comment: @EmtiazZahid , it showing me this  array:10 [▼
  "_token" => "AOY1JT1ImN5ZqJxHy8FjzwEkzETv34YE7KqFxdu5"
  "title" => "test title"
  "category_id" => "1"
  "subcategory_id" => "12"
  "type" => "quiz"
  "c_title" => "TEST TITLE TWO"
  "question" => "question two ?"
  "correct" => array:8 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "0"
    2 => "0"
    3 => "0"
    4 => "1"
    5 => "0"
    6 => "0"
    7 => "0"
  ]
  "answer" => array:8 [▼
    0 => "A"
    1 => "B"
    2 => "C"
    3 => "D"
    4 => "a"
    5 => "b"
    6 => "c"
    7 => "d"
  ]
  "optradio" => "4"
]

Comment: in your html c_title is not an array field. you should change it to c_title[] in field names

Comment: @EmtiazZahid, the error changed to ("Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `quizes` (`content_id`, `c_title`, `question`, `created_at`) values (308, title stack help, stack help, 2018-11-08 07:13:58))) but still not working. the answer table in DB is empty. thank you brother for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should add `c_title` as array in your input fields: `c_title`  to `c_title[]`

in your controller you will get the exception for assigning c_title array in c_title attribute. so you need to redesign your db table and code

```
$quiz_id = DB::table('quizes')->insertGetId([
      'content_id' =>$content_id,
      'c_title'=>$request->c_title, // its an array not string
      'question'=>$request->question,
      'created_at'=>now(), 
  ]);



  foreach ($request->c_title as $key => $value) {

      $new_answer->content_id=$content_id;
      $new_answer->quiz_id=$quiz_id;
      $new_answer->c_title =$request->c_title[$key];
      $new_answer->question=$request->question[$key];

      foreach ($request->answer as $key => $value) {
        $new_answer = new answer();
        $new_answer->answer =$request->answer[$key];
        $new_answer->correct=$request->correct[$key] ? 1 :0;
      }
```

Comment: you said its an array not string, please could you show me how. as i am new to laravel

Comment: for $new_answer table data you should use c_title[] in html. you changed it. and then your exception changed it to array to string conversion. 'c_title'=>$request->c_title, from here its showing error. because of c_title is an array you can store it in an single field

Comment: i am still suffering, Bytheway  thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: you are welcome. hope you will find out the problem and solve this. happy coding